# Do back links to a language subdirectory affect the rankings of all languages on the site?

Tags: seo, search-engines, backlinks, content, domain-authority

Consider `example.com` as the root of my French site and `example.com/en/` as the English version, and `example.com/ar/` as the Arabic version. All language versions are generated manually (not IP-based redirection or any other dynamic translation generation).

If I get a back link to my `/en/` URL, does it affect the other language's ranking or not? ie. does getting back link to one language version increase DA on root domain and the site as a whole?

Comment: Do your pages in different languages link to each other?

Comment: They are not duplicated translations, EN version is on its own and has unique content than every other version. The only link is for some systemic pages like "about us" or to the home page of all other versions through the nav menu

Comment: They are as if independent websites created for target language